# Statistics of changes for comapring file contents present in two different directories

Tags: bash, shell, unix, diff, solaris-10

On `Solaris 10`, I have two directories having mostly same set of files in both directories but there could be few files present only in one directory. the almost same list of files. With the `diff` command I can see individual differences. With a combination of `diff` with a `find` statement run in a for loop as below:

```
for  i in `find $DIRNM -type f`
```

I can check individual differences of the files. But, I need to have some statistics like how many got changed, how many lines added, how many lines deleted, and how many lines modified. How can i do that with the help of a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

If available on your system, I would use both `diff` and `diffstat`

```
diff -Naur dir1 dir2 | diffstat
```

Answer (score 0):

These bash commands will compare your two directory listings (by name, not content):

```sh
mylist() { find "$1" -type f |sed "s:$1::"; }
diff <(mylist dir1) <(mylist dir2)
```

It is possible that those end up being unsorted.  If that's the case, add `sort` to the helper function:

```sh
mylist() { find "$1" -type f |sed "s:$1::" |sort; }
```

These use [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) to run the two `find` commands and compare their results with `diff`.  If you want a side-by-side comparison, try `vimdiff` instead.  If the lines are very very long, you might want `vimdiff -o` to have the first output on top and the second output on the bottom.  If you also dislike `vim`, try `diff -y` instead.

To quantify differences in file contents, the easiest solution is `diff -ur dir1 dir2 |diffstat` as mentioned in [oliv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108523/statistics-of-changes-for-comapring-file-contents-present-in-two-different-direc#40108802). If you don't have that available, you can do it with `awk`:

```c
diff -Nur dir1 dir2 |awk '
  $1 == "+++" { new = $2 } # use $0 if you have filenames with spaces in them
  /^-/  { change[new]-- }
  /^\+/ { change[new]++ }
  END   { for (f in change) if (f) printf "%s %+d\n", f, change[f] }'
```

For the uninitiated, [`awk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is a field-separated conditionalized line-by-line parser.  By default, fields are split on whitespace, so that first clause says if the first field is `+++`, store the second field.  **If you have file names with spaces in them, assign `new = $0` instead.**  The second and third clause decrement or increment the counter for that file.

The final clause, which happens when the input has been exhausted, loops through each file (key) `f` in associative array (dictionary) `change`. Assuming it's not empty, we print the file and its number of changed lines.  I used `%+d` to give a `+` sign to positive values (like `diff`).

Whitespace, including line breaks, can be collapsed in `awk` code so long as you're not putting letters together (you can do `$1=="+++"{new=$2}/^-/{…` on one line without any spaces, but you cannot do `for(finchange)` because it will assume `finchange` is a variable).  Spacing is much more legible.

This outputs the total number of changed lines; a `+0` means that as many lines were added as subtracted, *not* that the file is unchanged.  It shouldn't be too hard to modify this code to count both additions and subtractions (simply use two hashes instead of one, then use two loops to print each per-file count individually in the final clause.)